# Run Sequential and Parallel tests in parallel with Selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to run my Selenium tests in Jenkins in parallel, so my suite was set to `<suite parallel="methods">`.
But now I have added some new tests that produce conflicts when running parallel. So what I need is a few tests running sequential while all the other tests run parallel at the same time.

What I came up with was:

```
<suite name="Testsuite" thread-count="1" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Parallel Tests" parallel="methods">
    <!-- Some parallel tests here -->
  </test>
  <test name="Sequential Tests" parallel="false">
    <!-- Some sequential tests here -->
  </test>
</suite>
```

But it does not seem to work. The parallel tests were not even executed at all. Can anyone help me and tell me what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: What framework/product/tool/language are you using? There is nothing in the post or tag about that.

Comment: I have e2e-tests with selenium and java running on jenkins

Comment: Are you using Junit/TestNG?

Comment: @eduPeeth TestNG

Comment: @CarleB.Navy - Please edit your question and add the following details. 1. TestNG version that you are using. 2. How are you running the tests (build tool details since you mentioned Jenkins). 3. Create and share a simple test project (without selenium because it has no role to play here), which we can execute to reproduce the problem. You can either upload the project to github and share a lin to it or create it as a zip and attach it.

Comment: instead of parallel = "tests", give parallel = "classes". Also remove parallel = "methods". Hope it will work.